# Does Xposed Framework require to be buillt specifically for the device or just the Android version?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-tab, command-line, xposed-framework

When installing the Xposed framework do I need the device specific binary (like custom recovery or ROM) or just the app that works for Android (4.4.4 in my case). The device is Galaxy Tab E T560.

**Update 12/7/2018**

I tried to Install the framework as on the custom ROM as well as on the stock firmware but with no luck. It seems that Xposed is device/arch/firmware dependent.

Comment: To my knowledge, there are no device specific builds. It just needs to match the Android version. Worked that way for me on multiple devices for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built for the Android version, plus the device architecture (arm/arm64/x86). See the Xposed Framework download page (e.g. Android 8.1 (SDK27) [here](https://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/sdk27/)).

The reason behind this is that part of Xposed Framework is a modified `app_process` binary (Zygote), which is different for each arch.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the info.  I heard that you must find the correct one and flash it via twrp. I am also downloading many versions for my T560 (Lineage OS) and cannot install any xposed app with Unknown sources set to on.

Comment: If you're rooted then you can also use the Xposed Installer app which should automatically find and download the correct stuff for your Android version and arch. What you described sounds like another problem entirely.

Comment: I am getting this error: Xposed is not (yet) compatible with Android SDK version 19 or your processor arch. ( armeabi-v7a). CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot link symbol "_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcS2_" referenced by "/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/cache/app_process". The device is also rooted with Chainfire SuperSU

Comment: @S4NNY1 Android 4.4? You'll need an *ancient* version (e.g. 2.6) of the installer.

Comment: Every damn version I try, the Install button is disabled and the error remains.

Comment: Then I have no more ideas. I don't have an Android device with Android version as low as 4.4 to test it out myself either...

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the effort. I'll try to somehow solve it and post the solution here it I find it. Thnak you again.

Comment: No problem, and please do, I'm also curious to see how it turns out.

Comment: It seems that it won't let ne install any XF on Linage OS.

Comment: I  have updated my post. I tried to Install Xposed on both custom and stock.